# Extras are null inside onNewIntent() method

Tags: java, android

I have a timer and when it ends if the user has it's app in background it sends a local notification, the local notification takes the user to the Timer `Activity`, this should fire the `onNewIntent()` method (that works on a device running Android L) where I check for the `Extras` I passed, the problem is that the `Extras` are null.

In the manifest I've declared my activity as: `android:launchMode="singleTop"`

And I create the notification like this:

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), CookingTimer.class);
notificationIntent.putExtra("stopTimer", true);
notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(this)
        .setContentTitle("Il Countdown è terminato!")
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setContentIntent(pIntent).build();
        //.addAction(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Stop", stopTimer)

NotificationManager notificationManager = 
        (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

notificationManager.notify(0, noti);
```

Why it doesn't work?

**EDIT:**

Just found that the `Extra` I pass using `notificationIntent.putExtra("stopTimer", true);` is null when I check inside the `onNewIntent()` method

Comment: onCreate is not called either?

Comment: Shouldn't you `start` the intent? I only use the `intent` right away, but then you have to call `context.startActivity(intent);`

Comment: @pskink no it's not getting called

Comment: so Activity is not started by the Notification?

Comment: @pskink no the activity is started and now I found that the method is called but the Extras of the Intent are null

Comment: use different requestCode in `getActivity`

Comment: @pskink can you give me an example please?

Comment: what examples? just call getActivity with different requestCode

Comment: @pskink Yeah sorry I wasn't understanding.. I already tried to set a random number but it didn't work

Comment: What `Intent` are you looking at in the `onNewIntent()` method?

Comment: @LarrySchiefer yeah I found the solution a bit ago, the problem was that I was using getIntent() instead of the intent passed by the method, now it's working as expected